# mysql_fetch_row() not a valid result resource

Tags: php, mysql, sql, rows

I am confused, I don't know what's wrong. I'm about to transfer all data from my first table to the other. Here is my code:

```
$getdata = mysql_query("SELECT Quantity, Description, Total FROM ordercart");

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($getdata))
{
foreach($row as $cell){

$query1 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO ordermem (Quantity, Description, Total) VALUES 
($cell)",$connect);

}
mysql_free_result($getdata);
}
```

I get the error: Warning: mysql_fetch_row(): 5 is not a valid MySQL result resource.

Comment: Use error messages to find out what goes wrong. The manual shows how. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: Please read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php). This example is a **serious** liability.

Answer (score 5):

You only pass one value in the `INSERT`, which expects three values to be passed to the fields  `Quantity, Description, Total`:

```
INSERT INTO ordermem (Quantity, Description, Total) VALUES 
($cell);
```

Change it to:

```
INSERT INTO ordermem (Quantity, Description, Total) VALUES 
($cell, $descriptionParam, $totalParam);
```

You may also try to use `INSERT INTO SELECT` directly instead of two distinct statements like so:

```
INSERT INTO ordermem (Quantity, Description, Total)
SELECT Quantity, Description, Total FROM ordercart;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to insert 1 value into 3 fields. You need to have 1 value for each field. For example:

```
$quantity="$_GET['qty']";
$description="$_GET['desc']";
$total="$_GET['total']";

$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO ordermem (Quantity, Description, Total) 
                                    VALUES ('$quantity','$description','$total'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use debugging to find out the source of your problem.

`mysql_query()` returns a boolean value that tells you whether the operation succeeded or not. If it did not succeed, the `mysql_error()` function give you mySQL's error message.

Example:

```
$query1 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO ordermem (Quantity, Description, Total) VALUES ($cell)",$connect);

if (!$query1)  
  trigger_error("mySQL Error: mySQL returned ".mysql_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
```

This will give you a message something like "Number of values does not match the number of columns", which gives you a hint about what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$query = "INSERT INTO ordermem (Quantity, Description, Total) SELECT Quantity, Description, Total FROM ordercart";

mysql_query($query);
```